# Which gear is this?

Tags: tire, shimano, gears

The tire on my bike below needs to be changed, but I am afraid of taking it off because of the internal seen below.

My concern is that if I take the wheel off then I either break something in the gear or that it needs be calibrated afterwards.

Searching for "shimano 7 gear" doesn't give me any videos on changing tires.

**Question**

Can someone tell me what I should search for on how to change the tire with such a gear?

[image]

Comment: Thats a shimano nexus internal gear hub. It looks like you have a coaster brake (back pedaling stops the bike? if so, then yes), so its a little more complicated than just unbolting the wheel and pulling it out.

Comment: Yes it is a coaster break. Can you explain what I need to do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to a video for your a Shimano Nexus wheel removal.

**Summary:**

1. firstly, take the bike outside or somewhere that can get dirty.  That bike's got a lot of dirt on it and it will make a mess.   Give it a clean with a rag or brush, this will help stop dirt getting in places it shouldn' be.  It makes the rest of the job easier too.
2. If you have rim brakes, open your brake quick release or deflate the tyre to allow the rim to come out easier.
3. Detach the gear cable by **COMPLETE THIS**
4. Undo the coaster brake cable by  **COMPLETE THIS**
5. Note the position of the axle nuts on the dropout. A quick outline with a marker pen is a good idea, on both sides.
6. Loosen the axle nuts
7. Slide the wheel along the dropouts.  This should leave the chain loose enough to extract the whole wheel and change the tyre.  Inflate the tyre and check it holds pressure before refitting.

Reverse installation process

1. Deflate the tyre if required to fit through the rim brakes.
2. Fit the wheel into the dropouts and fit the chain to the cog at the same time.
3. Set the tension on the chain appropriately.  You should be exactly on the axle nut marks from earlier.
4. Hook up the coaster brake cable  **COMPLETE THIS**
5. Connect the gear cable  **COMPLETE THIS**
6. Inflate tyre to required pressures, if necessary.
7. Test brakes and gears, then go on a short test ride.

Note - if you're only patching a tube, its possible to do this without removing the wheel.  Changing the tube requires removal though.

Comment: Sorry.. I will edit it with the direct link

Comment: @dafew I'll add an example of how you might summarise the video. should it become unavailable.  Please complete it.

Comment: In my case I don't have the yellow dots he talks about in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b-IHIuSbRhY to adjust the gears afterwards. What should I do in this case?